# Discord Py - how do i delete selective channels from a category

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is the code:

```py
    @commands.command(aliases=['delallchannel'])
    async def deleteAllChannel(self, ctx):
        category_name = "Pets_Private_Channels"
        categoryName = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=category_name)
        categoryID = categoryName.id

        globalChannel1 = "1_pets_global_channel"
        globalChannel2 = "2_pets_global_channel"
        globalChannel3 = "3_pets_global_channel"

        #print(categoryID)
        category = self.client.get_channel(categoryID)
        for channel in category.text_channels:
            #print(channel ," This is the channel")
            if channel == globalChannel1:
                print(globalChannel1)
            elif channel == globalChannel2:
                print(globalChannel2)
            elif channel == globalChannel3:
                print(globalChannel3)
            else:
                await channel.delete()
        #if channel != globalChannel1 or channel != globalchannel2 or channel != globalchannel3:
            #await channel.delete()
``
Im having some difficulties trying to write a command that would delete all channels but not 3 selected ones within a set category. I think the issue could be to do with the if statement. Even when the `channel == globalchannel` is the same value, it still skips to else. Does anyone know why? or how i could fix this issue?

Thanks in advance. Much appreciated for anyone that is helping out on this.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking if the `discord.TextChannel` object is equal to a string. There are two ways you can do this:

You can cast the channel to a string, this will cause it to equal the name of the channel.

```py
for channel in category.text_channels:
    if str(channel) == globalChannel1:
        print(globalChannel1)
    # continue with other if statements
```

OR you can `discord.utils.get` the channel.

```py
globalChannel1 = discord.utils.get(category.text_channels, name="1_pets_global_channel") 
# Repeat for other channels
```

Note that both only work if the channel name is the same as the string. It is case-sensitive.

Also, note that you're getting a channel and from a category ID. You should just do this...

```py
category_name = "Pets_Private_Channels"

# ... other stuff

category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=category_name)
```

Comment: Idk whats going on with me, similar thing happened to me yesterday where i tried some stuff then the next day i try the same code again and it works...

Comment: 1St comment - Yh ive tried str(channel), even tried doing str(channel) == str(globalChannel1) despite knowing globalchannel was already a string. and yh ive also tried ur second recommendation before posting this thread but that also didnt seem to work.

Comment: Ohh wait i figured out why now it was because i was using if str(channel) != globalChannel1 or str(channel)!= globalchannel2 or str(channel)!= globalchannel3: